# pdc->GetOutputTextExtent() crashes

Tags: visual-c++

pdc->GetOutputTextExtent() crashes, if nCount = -1.  Why?  The manual says:

nCount
Specifies the number of characters in the string. If nCount is -1, the length is calculated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(AFXWIN%2FCDC%3A%3AGetOutputTextExtent)%3Bk(CDC%3A%3AGetOutputTextExtent)%3Bk(GetOutputTextExtent)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2017#getoutputtextextent

Answer (score 0):

It appears the manual is wrong.  Internally, it is implemented like this:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CSize CDC::

GetOutputTextExtent(LPCTSTR lpszString, int nCount) const
    {
        ASSERT(m_hDC != NULL);
        SIZE size;
        VERIFY(::GetTextExtentPoint32(m_hDC, lpszString, nCount, &size));
        return size;
    }
```

And, `GetTextExtentPoint32` docs do *not* mention that -1 will auto-calculate.

However, there's an overload sibling taking just a string that does the count itself:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE CSize CDC::GetOutputTextExtent(const CString& str) const
    {
        ASSERT(m_hDC != NULL);
        SIZE size;
        VERIFY(::GetTextExtentPoint32(m_hDC, str, (int)str.GetLength(), &size));
        return size;
    }
```